# Optimizing search on map

Tags: search, optimization, dictionary, coordinates

for one of our clients we are providing a system for retrieving the closest N landmarks from the users zipcode location. 
We have a database of all the available zipcodes (650,000+) with the coresponding coordinates (latitude and longitude) and also all of 400+ landmarks in the country.

For now we are using the following process from finding closest N landmarks

1. Retrieve the lat and lng of the selected zipcode
2. Get the coordinates of all the landmarks
3. Order them by using a geographic distance formula
4. Take the closest N+2 landmarks and get the real distance to them using the following process

   - check if the distance between coordinates is stored in the distance cache table
   - if not it goes to a map engine, retrieved the distance and stores it in the cache
5. Reorder the list and return first N closest landmarks

The problem is we need to optimize this both from database access point of view and 3rd party access also.

We have tried to cache for all zipcodes the distance to closest M landmarks but the table would gain an additional 6Gb of data and it would take around 250 days to fill since a request takes aprox 30 sec.

We were thinking on partitioning the data and grouping close postcodes together but that will void the exact distance.

What optimising solutions you see in this situation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an repetitive approach.

1. Pick a value to use as your "radius"
2. Go through all results and pick only ones +- radius horizontally and vertically (according to geolocation
3. if not enough rows returned, increase "radius" and start again
4. Now perform distance calculation and use a PriorityQueue to minimise the number of calculations used in this sort and select the required items

Comment: this is a good optimization for the aprox distance to the landmark, but we need an exact road distance, thus the additional step to 3rd party providers is still needed.

Comment: Oh, well you can keep this optimization only have the radius maybe 3 times larger than actually requested, its unlikley that to get to a point 7 miles away, you'd need to travel more than 21 miles. For the distance calculation, your cache approach is excellent, but 30seconds for finding the a distance from the provider seems very slow...

Comment: And I'd imagine its going to be your best point for improvement

Comment: well the 30 seconds thing is mostly due to the limits from google and yahoo, cause we are talking about more than 400 requests per zipcode. The more we are thinking on this the more is a matter of finding a way to represent data in an efficient way.

Comment: Well as long as you require exact distances according to roads, then without paid access to that data, I'm not sure how it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done on database- level. You should use a database with an geographic extension as SQL Server 2008 R2, or the excellent open source choise PostGre SQL with PostGIS extension. With those you store Geographical BLOBs instead of coordinates, and there are many built in functions to calculate geography that will take care of step 2 to 5 for you.

I suggest you start here:
http://postgis.refractions.net/

Regards

Comment: The problem is we need exact travel by road distances, that's why we rely on google maps and yahoo maps in the last step. The database part is running quite smooth. This is most likely a problem of creating a cache so big so we don't need to go to Google/Yahoo